# Installing helm Redash on Minikube return Error(redash-scheduler container redis connection error)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minikube, redash

I tried to set up Redash on a local environment using Minikube and Helm, but encountered an Two errors.

- The Minikube cluster is configured with `4 CPUs` and `8GB` of memory.
- The Helm Redash URL used is https://github.com/getredash/contrib-helm-chart.
- Two errors occurred during this process.

  - `OSError: [Errno 99] cannot assign requested address`
  - `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError`

---

During the process of creating the Redash environment, an `access denied` error occurred when executing `mkdir` command in redis and postgresql Pod, so I solved the problem by creating `local-path` storgae instead of using `standard` storage.

---

After that, when we create Redash with Helm, problems occur in two pods, as shown in the second screenshot.

- Some pods that create redash-server containers and redash-scheduler containers have problems.
  Especially, an error similar to the first screenshot continues to occur in Redash-scheduler.

---

To reproduce, you can simply enter the following command.

- labtop & OS version : m1 mac Monterey 12.1
- minikube version : v1.30.1
- kubectl version : 1.27.1
- helm version : v3.8.2
- helm redash version : 3.0.0(latest)

```bash
# minikube start
$ minikube start --nodes 3 --driver=docker

# default addson turn-off
$ minikube addons disable storage-provisioner

# setting local-path-storge by rancher and change default storage
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/local-path-provisioner/v0.0.20/deploy/local-path-storage.yaml
$ kubectl patch storageclass local-path  -p '{"metadata": {"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"}}}'

# make redash necessary values.yaml and helm install redash
$ cat > my-values.yaml <<- EOM
redash:
  cookieSecret: $(openssl rand -base64 32)
  secretKey: $(openssl rand -base64 32)
postgresql:
  postgresqlPassword: $(openssl rand -base64 32)
redis:
  password: $(openssl rand -base64 32)
EOM

# add helm repo
$ helm repo add redash https://getredash.github.io/contrib-helm-chart/

# launch helm redash
$ helm upgrade --install -f my-values.yaml my-release redash/redash
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace the collection of images with a [mcve]?  This should include the error message in plain text, the Helm template code you've written that causes it, and any other required information like the corresponding set of Helm values you're using at deploy time.